# I want change cell values from some sheet in many sheet by google spread sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function UpdateCell()
{
  const NotationRange = "J1";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const year = 2020;
  sheets.forEach
  (
    (sheet) => 
    { const sheetName = sheet.getName();
       { sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
       }
    }
  )
}
```

in google spreadsheet script

upper code is work well and fast
but, It change all of sheet

sheet name has rule. so, it can be distinguished

what I want is change cell value in specific sheet that sheet name contain [week]

in my sheet name are [Reference],[01.01],[01.02],,,,[12.31],[week01],[week02],,,[week53]

so I tried but fail..

```
function UpdateCell()
{
  const NotationRange = "B2:D5"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const year = 2020
  const checkDailyWord = ".";
  const checkWeekWord = "week";
  var DC = new RegExp('\\b' + checkDailyWord + '\\b');
  var WC = new RegExp('\\b' + checkWeekWord + '\\b');
  sheets.forEach
  (
    (sheet) => 
    { const sheetName = sheet.getName();
       if( DC.sheetName == 1 )
       { sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
       }
       if( WC.sheetName == 1 )
       { sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'week'+sheetName);
       }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `new RegExp` has no property of `sheetName`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) By this, `undefined` is alwasy returned. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- In your case, I think that `includes` can be used for the if statement.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function UpdateCell() {
  const NotationRange = "B2:D5"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const year = 2020
  const checkDailyWord = ".";
  const checkWeekWord = "week";
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    if (sheetName.includes(checkDailyWord) && !sheetName.includes(checkWeekWord)) {
      sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName);
    } else if (!sheetName.includes(checkDailyWord) && sheetName.includes(checkWeekWord)) {
      sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'week'+sheetName);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this modified script is run, in your sample sheet names, `01.01,01.02,12.31` and `week01,week02,week53` run `sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'.'+sheetName)` and `sheet.getRange(NotationRange).setValue(year+'week'+sheetName)`, respectively.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, from your sample sheet names, it supposes that the sheets with the sheet name includes both `week` and `.` are not used.

#### Reference:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)